# Access base type array members (Int-to-Type idiom)

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

Attempting to implement the Int-to-Type idiom, I've run into a problem inside my inherited class that I'm not able to resolve even after trying several similar solutions from other posts here. I'm attempting to implement a simple sort algorithm on an array in an inherited class. To start, I setup the int-to-type enum and struct:

```
enum class Technique : int
{
    NOOP,
    INSERTION_SORT,
    QUICK_SORT
};
template <Technique I>
struct AutoTechnique
{
    enum { value = I };
};
```

Next, I define my Array class inheriting from std::array with some tooling to handle different sort techniques based on the size of the collection:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
class Array : public std::array<T, N>
{
    static const Technique technique = (N == 0 || N == 1) ? Technique::NOOP :
        (N < 50) ? Technique::INSERTION_SORT : Technique::QUICK_SORT;

    void sort(AutoTechnique<Technique::NOOP>)
    {
        std::cout << "NOOP\n";
    }
    void sort(AutoTechnique<Technique::INSERTION_SORT>)
    {
        int i, j;
        T temp;
        for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && this[j - 1] > this[j])
            {
                temp = this[j]; // Wants to assign Array<T,N> to temp, rather than value at index.
                this[j] = this[j - 1];
                this[j - 1] = temp;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    void sort(AutoTechnique<Technique::QUICK_SORT>)
    {
        std::cout << "QUICK_SORT\n";
    }
public:
    void Sort()
    {
        sort(AutoTechnique<technique>());
    }
```

};

The problem is on the line with the comment, the compiler is telling me `"= cannot convert from Array<int,49> to T"` (int,49 being a test case).

The best answer I could find that was close to this was a suggestion that I need to dereference this (*this) and access the value with ->, but the code two lines above appears to work, where I'm not doing that, and several variations on attempting to dereference the object did not work.

It seems the main problem is with the attempt to assign the value in this[j] to T temp. I tried casting `(T)this[j]` and I get an error that `type cast cannot convert...`

How do I store the value in an index of `this` array in a temporary variable which matches the type provided to the array?

Comment: `this[j]` even if correct, why do you want to write code like that? I find it quite confusing, is supposed to be `*(this + j)` or `this->operator[](j)` ?

Comment: The suggestion you found was correct.  You need `(*this)[whatever]`.

Comment: `this[j - 1] > this[j]` may 'work' in that it compiles, but based on the error you do get, perhaps isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: That was the correct format of the code, I swear I tried ten other variants ;)

Comment: please dont do corrections in the question. Questions are for the question. Answers should go to the answer ;). You can answer your own question, but imho adding the correct code to the question makes it more difficult to read the question rather than the opposite

Comment: Wasn't really clear, in some places you can flag a topic as answered, but I didn't see anything like that here, so I figured putting the answer in the question made the most sense, so that the original post contained the accepted answer. Guess it's just another stackoverflow thing I'll have to get used to. I think I'm at least getting better at asking questions that can be answered! Thanks.

Comment: you can click on the checkmark next to one of the answers to accept it, the main difference is probably that SO is not a forum but a Q&A, its rather common that there are more than one good answers, though you can only accept one

Comment: To directly answer your first question, there are certain scenarios that I'm working with where I need to use an array rather than a vector. I have a Vector class that does exactly what this one does in half the code. I was aiming for a consistent interface. In this case Array::Sort() now functions the same way as my Vector::Sort() does. Based on some threshold value, I sort using different techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Let me use an example...

```
class foo {};

int main() {
    foo* a;
    a+5;       // fine ? 
    a[3];      // fine ? 
    foo b;
    b+5;       // error: no operator found
    b[3];      // error: no operator found
}
```

There are certain operators for pointers (the example is not complete, the point is just to demonstrate that they are not the operators for objects). They work for pointers of any type. You are consufing operations on pointers with operations on instances. Comparing pointers is not the same as comparing the objects.

Moreover, when `a` is a pointer, then `a[b]` is just `*(a+b)`. Hence, in your code it appears to work, but in fact it does not. You treat `this` as if it was a pointer to an array of objects and then you dereference it at memory locations where there is no `Array` objects (you only have one, not an array of them). Actually you are accessing out-of-bounds and your code has undefined behaviour.

The error message actually explains what is wrong:

> = cannot convert from Array to T

Because here

```
temp = this[j];
```

`temp` is of course a `T` while `this[j] == *(this + j)`, ie you increment the `this` pointer by `j`-times the `sizeof(Array<int,49>)` (thats what happens when you add an integer to a pointer of a certain type) and then you dereference the pointer to get a `Array<int,49>`. There is no assignment operator for those types, hence the error.

Moreover, there is no `Array<int,49>` at that memory location. Actually you are lucky to get a compiler error, usually undefined behaviour is more lurky, hiding behind innocent looking warnings or even worse no warning and appearing to work when it actually is not.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I had not considered the obvious nuance of pointer logic on arrays, and like a string the array pointer would be what you'd get from `this`.

Comment: @AaronStackpole I am not 100% sure, but I think i would rather write `operator[](j)` instead of `(*this)[j]`. Less stars `*` is always nice and it makes it a bit more obvious that you are calling the inherited operator.

Comment: Do you think there would be an inherent performance difference between using the operator versus accessing the pointer? Would the compiler optimize any difference away anyway?

Comment: @AaronStackpole there is no performance difference whatsoever, its just about readability. choose the style you like, though the chances to make the mistake that lead to this question are highly reduced if you write `operator[](j)` instead of `(*this)[j]`. From the latter I just need to remove a tiny `*` to change its meaning completely and make it silently do the wrong thing, with the first I dont know any typo that could do the same from the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

Updated code from answer provided by @NathanOliver

```
void sort(AutoTechnique<Technique::INSERTION_SORT>)
{
    int i, j;
    T temp;
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && (*this)[j - 1] > (*this)[j])
        {
            temp = (*this)[j];
            (*this)[j] = (*this)[j - 1];
            (*this)[j - 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```